# How to encode the html entities using php

Tags: php, encoding

I am using ck editor to compose my mail , to send mails to my user I am using the libmail class. my issue is if I echo the posted data from the ckeditor 
eg:  echo   $message   = $_POST['editor1'];
            output     : "  < data >  "
but if I send the message using the libmail the mail sended like this

```
<p>
    &quot;&nbsp; &lt; data &gt;&nbsp; &quot;</p>
<br />
```

I already tried this combination:

1 . $message =  strip_tags($message);
 2 . $message = htmlentities($message,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
 3 . $message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($message)));

Still I could not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried the **encoding** functions. What you need is the **decoding** ones.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: yes i already mention in my post, i tried these string function 1 . $message = strip_tags($message); 2 . $message = htmlentities($message,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'); 3 . $message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($message))); . still the outputlooks like same

Comment: No, you tried the **encoding** functions. What you need is the **decoding** ones.